# When using Report.DataSourceConnections: "Object reference not set to an instance of an object"

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

Please see the below code.  I think it's pretty self explanatory.  I'm running VS2010 along with Crystal Reports for VS2010.  Crazy thing is I have a similar project with similar code which doesn't generate an exception on that line...so I've been trying to figure out the difference between the two projects but have came up empty so far.

Thanks for any advice or ideas on how to fix this!

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using CrystalDecisions.Shared;
using CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine;

public partial class Reports : System.Web.UI.Page
{
  ReportDocument rptSP;


protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   rptSP = new ReportDocument();
   string rptPath = Server.MapPath(Request.QueryString["rptname"].ToString());
   rptSP.Load(rptPath, 0);
   rptSP.DataSourceConnections["MyServer\\MyInst", "MyDB"].SetConnection("MyServer\\MyInst", "MyDB", "MyUsername", "MyPass");
//The above line causes an excepton while debugging on my local development machine
```

If it matters on my aspx page I have the following:

```
<%@ Register Assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"
Namespace="CrystalDecisions.Web" TagPrefix="CR" %>
```

And then in my web.config I have:

```
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportSource, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Shared, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.Web, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
            <add assembly="CrystalDecisions.ReportAppServer.ClientDoc, Version=13.0.2000.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=692fbea5521e1304"/>
```

along with a few other Crystal DLLs in my BIN directory.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```
rptSP.DataSourceConnections[@"MyServer\MyInst", "MyDB"].SetConnection(@"MyServer\MyInst", "MyDB", "MyUsername", "MyPass");
```

Notice the replacement of double backslashes with single ones, and the attendant @ symbol to go with them. I prefer this way to double backslashes because then I control the string formatting explicitly.